# Why does object_id always return null?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT object_id('dbo.groups','U'); //NULL
```

[image]

Comment: Are you connect the to correct DB?

Comment: Have you tried to refresh Tables folder in Object Explorer?

Answer (score 6):

OBJECT_ID returns NULL on error.

A user can only view the metadata of securables that the user owns or on which the user has been granted permission. This means that metadata-emitting, built-in functions such as OBJECT_ID may return NULL if the user does not have any permission on the object.

For more information, see [Metadata Visibility Configuration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190328.aspx).

Comment: What if I am db_owner and it still returns null. Answer: missing schema...