# T-SQL OBJECT_ID always returning NULL even though metadata exists and user has correct permissions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm always getting null when I call OBJECT_ID with a valid object name. E.g.

```
use [My-Database];
declare @objectId int;

SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE name = 'DF_FieldStatusTypes_DisplayOrder'
SELECT @objectId = object_id FROM sys.objects WHERE name = 'DF_FieldStatusTypes_DisplayOrder'
SELECT @objectId
SELECT object_name(@objectId)
SELECT object_id(object_name(@objectId))
SELECT object_id('DF_FieldStatusTypes_DisplayOrder')
```

The results produced are as follows:

```
(1) DF_FieldStatusTypes_DisplayOrder| 753437758 | NULL | 5 | 241435934 | D | DEFAULT_CONSTRAINT | 2020-10-17 11:08:13.520 | 2020-10-17 11:08:13.520 | 0 | 0 | 0  
(2) 753437758  
(3) DF_FieldStatusTypes_DisplayOrder  
(4) NULL
(5) NULL
```

Results 1 through 3 are accurate, but 4 and 5 always return NULL. The Stack question I reference below is similar and quotes the Microsoft [article for OBJECT_ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/object-id-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#examples) where it states:

> ... metadata-emitting, built-in functions such as OBJECT_ID may return
> NULL if the user does not have any permission on the object.

But, the exact same information is stated under the Exceptions section of the [article for OBJECT_NAME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/object-name-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks)

In my case however the OBJECT_NAME function is called successfully and OBJECT_ID always returns null.

What am I missing?

---

**Similar Question**

[Why does object_id always returns null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28146114/why-does-object-id-always-returns-null)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a stab in the dark, but I suspect the hint of why is in your first result set. `schema_id` has a value of `5` which means it isn't on the `dbo` schema. As such I suspect that your default schema is *not* the schema that said object is on.

Take the following statements:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.SomeTable (ID int
                                CONSTRAINT DF_ID
                                    DEFAULT 0);
GO

DECLARE @objectId int;

SELECT *
FROM sys.objects
WHERE name = 'DF_ID';

SELECT @objectId = object_id
FROM sys.objects
WHERE name = 'DF_ID';

SELECT @objectId;

SELECT OBJECT_NAME(@objectId);

SELECT OBJECT_ID(OBJECT_NAME(@objectId));

SELECT OBJECT_ID('DF_ID');
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.SomeTable;
```

This returns a non-`NULL` value for all data sets. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7223a7bf12a881ee83be5529bdbb106a)

Now let's use a different schema, that isn't my default.

```sql
CREATE SCHEMA another;
GO

CREATE TABLE another.SomeTable (ID int
                                CONSTRAINT DF_ID
                                    DEFAULT 0);
GO

DECLARE @objectId int;

SELECT *
FROM sys.objects
WHERE name = 'DF_ID';

SELECT @objectId = object_id
FROM sys.objects
WHERE name = 'DF_ID';

SELECT @objectId;

SELECT OBJECT_NAME(@objectId);

SELECT OBJECT_ID(OBJECT_NAME(@objectId));

SELECT OBJECT_ID('DF_ID');
GO

DROP TABLE another.SomeTable;
GO
DROP SCHEMA another
```

This, on the other hand returns the result you have: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=39468bc3c030a8c842cc114d2ab73c9c)

So, why is this? Well, `OBJECT_NAME` only returns the name of the object, not the name and schema. As such, `DF_ID` would be inferred to be the object `DF_ID` on the schema `dbo`; there is no such object on the `dbo` schema with that name.

If the schema name was included, you would get results: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=001d4eec9eb72f98ae983a7c05413b41)

Of course, you would never use the object id, to get the object name, to get the object name, so the problem you have is a little nonsensical.

Comment: Nope, would never use it that way, but was looking for a bunch of different approaches to see where it went wrong.
+1 for a complete answer - thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the schema. From the `sys.objects` result it shows the object belongs to `schema_id = 5`. So try:

```
SELECT OBJECT_ID(SCHEMA_NAME(5) + N'.' + OBJECT_NAME(@objectId));
```

Answer (score 1):

> What am I missing?

Your `sys.objects` query does not consider the object schema and will return rows regardless of the table schema. `OBJECT_ID` will return `NULL` when the table is not in your default schema and the object name is not qualified.

Try schema-qualifying the constraint name. `dbo` schema example:

```
SELECT OBJECT_ID('dbo.DF_FieldStatusTypes_DisplayOrder');
```